# ORC file metadata: writing custom key value?

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet, orc

Is there a way to write additional metadata to ORC file ? I found a way to do that in parquet using the "KeyValueMetadata". I looked at the UserMetadataItem class but I am not sure if Orc provides a way to add custom metadata. I want to find a way using java.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom key-value pairs to the metadata of an ORC file. The only restriction is that within a Key-Value pair, the Key must be a String, and the Value a binary.

See here for more information: https://orc.apache.org/docs/file-tail.html#user-metadata